# Is tablet windows 8.1 and pc/Laptop windows 8.1 are different?

Tags: windows, tablet

I am wondering if I can format and install windows 8.1 of my PC to my windows 8.1 tablet?

Or

there is an specialized Windows 8.1 OS for Win tablets?

**Tablet specification:**

Screen Size:    10.1 inch

OS: Dual-boot, Windows 8.1 32 Bit (Not Win 8.1 RT), Android 4.4

Screen Type:    Capacitive, IPS, 10-point multi-touch

Screen Resolution:  1920 x 1200 (16:10)

CPU Brand:  Intel

CPU Model:  Z3735F

CPU Cores:  Quad Core

CPU:    **Intel Atom Baytrail-T Z3735F Quad-core Processor**

CPU Frequency:  1.83GHz

GPU:    Intel HD Graphic

RAM:    2GB

ROM:    32GB

Memory Card Types:  TF/Micro SD card

Maximum Storage Extension:  128GB

Function:   WiFi, Bluetooth 4.0, GPS, A-GPS, OTG, Miracast

WiFi:   802.11 b/g/n, WiFi hotspot

Network Type:   1 SIM Card 1 Standby（Micro SIM card）

Unlocked:   Yes(without contract)

3G: WCDMA 900MHz, WCDMA 2100MHz

2G Network Frequency:   850MHz, 900MHz, 1800MHz, 1900MHz

Camera: 5MP back camera , 2MP front camera

Sensor: Gravity Sensor

Battery:    6800mAh

Audio Format:   MP3, WAV, WMA, AMR, MID, OGG, FLAC, AAC

Picture Format: JPG, BMP, GIF, PNG

Video Format:   4K, 2160P, 1080P, 720P, MP4, 3GP, AVI, DAT, FLV, MPG, RMVB, MKV, MOV

E-book Format:  TXT, CHM, UMD, PDF, etc.

Google Play:    Yes

Extend Port:    TF Card Slot, SIM Card Slot, Micro USB Port, 3.5mm Earphones Port

Comment: Depends. What kind of tablet do you have?

Comment: I think you are thinking of Win RT

Comment: We need more information.  Windows 8.1 is Windows 8.1 `Windows RT (8.x)` while based on `Windows 8.x` is not actually `Windows 8.x`

Comment: tablets often run only a 32Bit Windows, because of 32Bit firmware. So if you have a 64Bit Windows 8.x, you can't use it.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Win 8.1 32bit OS is running on Intel Atom Z3735F 64 bit CPU. Let me know if any more information you want.

Comment: and which Windows 8.1 do you have on your PC? Also 32Bit? if 64Bit, this doesn't work. And why do you want to change the Windows 8.1? Also next time post @ my username so that I get notified about your reply

Comment: Thanks @magicandre1981 it is Win 8.1 Pro 32bit OS. I want to upgrade it to 64bit OS or may be Win 10 32bit OS.

Comment: you can't upgrade to 64Bit. The firmware is mostly 32Bit only and blocks setup of 64Bit.

Comment: @magicandre1981 if some problem will happen to current os can i use pc win 8.1 32bit os to repair or reinstall?

Comment: OEM systems have a recovery partition where you an restore a broken Windows.

Comment: @magicandre1981 so i cant use pc win 8.1 32 bit os on my tab?

Comment: if you deleted the recovery partition download a 32Bit ISO from MSDN, this one works with your tablet. Now you have to download and all drivers for your tablet. Setup detects the key from the UEFI, so your windows will activate fine again.

Comment: Thanks @magicandre1981 but Still I don't get my answer. Can I use the ISO of Win 8.1 32bit os which I use to repair my PC? or Can I have a link for Win 8.1 if I am not wasting your time please ??

Answer (score 0):

I want to answer my own question. (If your tablet is not running on Windows 8.1 RT)

Mostly tablets are running on windows 8.1 with Bling version. You can remove that windows OS and can reinstall windows 8.1 Pro or Ultimate or anything in your tablet. You can use your tablet as a PC and procedure of flashing is same as a PC through USB.

NB: Make sure you have backup the whole driver before proceeding to reintall OS.